# How can I insert an unordered list inside a note in Markdown without losing the note?

Tags: markdown, documentation, mkdocs

How to add an unordered list inside a note in Markdown without additional extensions? I tried the following syntax but the Note disappears and the unordered list appears without being enclosed in a note. Is there a workaround to insert a list into a note?

> ***NOTE:***

- hello
- hi

Comment: You should show the Markdown syntax that you're trying in a code block.

Answer (score 2):

When I understand it correctly you would like to have something like:

> ***NOTE:***
>
> - hello
> - hi

I could accomplish this by means of:

```
> **_NOTE:_**  
> * hello
> * hi
```

i.e. by placing the entire required text in blockquotes